# Is parentViewController always a Navigation controller? iPhone SDK bugs collection

Tags: iphone

I've just found [exactly same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244588/is-parentviewcontroller-always-a-navigation-controller/994164#994164) but answers mostly connected to problem workaround... 
Is this fact (for me it looks like a bug) so obvious(or well-known) that peoples do not even try to find explanation?

In case this is really well-known bug in SDK...  **Can somebody share his experience about *most famous* bugs in iPhone SDK (up to 2.2.1 FW)?** It would be very useful to collect them and avoid needless questions.

Returning back to discussed issue...
I'm still interested: *Is parentViewController always a Navigation controller?* (in described conditions: [similar question  at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244588/is-parentviewcontroller-always-a-navigation-controller/994164#994164))

I've built same controllers sequence at my app and was confused.

Apple doc told us:

> **parentViewController** 
>   *The underlying view controller if this
>   view controller is a modal view
>   controller; otherwise, the enclosing
>   navigation or tab bar controller. nil
>   if none of these are present.
>   (read-only)* 
>  [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController)

In our case we have underlying view controller but nevertheless received navigation controller. So what is it? Do we have same value at  *navigationController* and *parentViewController*?

Thank you, Mike/

Comment: I dunno but the guy who asked that original question is fantastically good-looking.

Answer (score 2):

parentViewController is not always a navigationController.  Here's a case where it's not:

```
MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

UIScrollView *aScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

[aScrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];

aViewController.parentViewController==aScrollView; //returns yes
```

The parentViewController is the most immediate view controller above the current view controller in the hierarchy.  In some cases this can be a navigation controller, but it need not be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Is your app (you quoted from) include Navigation Controller at all?
I will try to repeat your sample later in evening my time.
Anyway thank you!

Comment: I've tried same sequence and get nil as parentViewController and it looks right.
parentViewController is UIViewController type but UIScrollView is UIView derived.