# updating value of modal view variable

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a modal view which displays the champion of my app.
there's a NSMutableString variable called champ in modal view,
which is supposed to be updated by returnChamp function in main view.
the champ string is correctly set in main view,
but in modal view, the champ value appears as (null).
In fact, it seems it doesn't even go into the returnChamp function.
so apparently something wrong with my calling or implementing returnChamp,
but I have another function that does the similar, and that works fine.

could anyone please help me?

```
-(void) mainView{
.....
        champ = [[currentPlayers objectAtIndex:playerIndex] retain];
        NSLog(@"%@",champ);
        modalWinner = [[winner alloc] init];
        modalWinner.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:modalWinner animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (NSMutableString *) returnChamp{
NSLog(@"returnChamp");
return champ;
```

}

```
//in modalWinner
-(void) modalView{
..............


champName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [(MainViewController *)self.parentViewController returnChamp]);
champName = [(MainViewController *)self.parentViewController returnChamp];
UIImage *champImage = [UIImage imageNamed:champName];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.parentViewController` is probably not actually a reference to your object.  For some reason, it seems that the framework always insists on setting a `UINavigationController` as `self.parentViewController` - even for modals, and to the extent that it will create one if there isn't already one.  This is probably going unnoticed because you're casting it to your `MainViewController` type.

You'll need to find a different way of making your original object available to be communicated with, or perhaps pass the appropriate value to the newly-instantiated controller before you present it.

For example, if you add a `champName` property to the modal class, you can do:

`modalWinner = [[ModalWinnerViewController alloc] init];

modalWinner.champName = myValue; /* Set value before presenting controller */

[self presentModalViewController:modalWinner animated:YES];`

There will probably be some code needed to update the UI with this value.  The `viewWillAppear` method of the modal view controller is a good place for this as it is called by the framework immediately before the view is presented.

Note that this property-based approach could be used to keep a reference to your intended parent object, as well.  And [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244588/is-parentviewcontroller-always-a-navigation-controller) for a different approach to solving a similar problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But What other ways could there be to update champName from mainview?

Comment: There are a few possible ways - probably the easiest would be to add a property (for example, "score") to the winner view controller and set the value of modalWinner.score before presenting the controller.  If there's any code that needs to be executed to handle display of the value you could put that in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried modalWinner.champName = champ; from main view, but it gives me "Object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found" error... If I were to set the value in viewWillAppear of modal view, how would I access it from main view?

Comment: You need to declare the `champName` property in the .h file for whatever class `modalWinner` is (let's call it `ModalWinnerViewController`), and then have `@synthesize champName` in the .m file for that same class.  Then, immediately after `winner = [[ModalWinnerViewController alloc] init]` set `winner.champName = champ`.  If there's code needed to then take that updated value and change UI elements to reflect it, put that code in the `viewWillAppear` method of the `ModalWinnerViewController` and the app will run it immediately before the view is presented.  I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244588/is-parentviewcontroller-always-a-navigation-controller) for a different solution to a similar problem.